# Генерация реферальной ссылки Telegram бота на Python 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Добрый день!

Подскажите, как можно генерировать реферальные ссылки на Telegram бота?
А затем, пользователю, по ссылке которого перешли на бота, начислять бонус?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep Linking: https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

Позволяет запускать бота с параметрами

Например:

`https://telegram.me/%bot_username%?refCode=%UNIQ_REF_CODE%`

и по %UNIQ_REF_CODE% начислять бонусы. Сам код должен генерировать уже бот